# добавление элементов списка из разных activity и их сохранение

Tags: java, android

Залача такая :есть 2 активити, с общими конструкциями, и разными textview

```
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map;

  SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, myArrList, R.layout.row)
```

Каждая передает свой интент из textview в общий список. Как реализовать, чтобы эти два интента из разных активити плюсовались по мере добавления, и было 2 пункта списка, даже после закрытия активити со списком, или перехода в другое(когда кликаешь "назад")? На подобе корзины покупок в магазинах.

Comment: Лучшим решением будет использовать базу данных, но для примитивной (учебной) задачи можно ограничится SharedPreferences. В БД создаешь таблицу и из каждой активити добавляешь туда записи. Когда требуется, выводишь эти записи в список. Интенты и коллекции здесь лишнее.

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос решен.